# Git in Eclipse: Files removed from local projects

Tags: eclipse, git, project

I am currently working on a few project in Eclipse. I wanted to use a version software and chose Git which seems very good.

I decided to share project on a network drive. In Eclipse, i clicked TEAM> SHARE PROJECT and chose a repository on this network drive.

All my files have been moved to this repository and there is nothing left in my local workspace. I don't understand why all files are gone. Could you please explain me what I did wrong to have all me files removed (those are used as dependencies in other projects so really need them on my local drive)

Also, what can I do to have my local copy of those files and push/commit whenever I think the files are ready to be committed.

Edit:
I found some comment corresponding to my problem on a website:

> I just tried this with EGit in Eclipse 3.7 Indigo. Sharing a project
>   will not allow the repository to reside within the project folder.
>   There is an option to use the parent folder of the project, but this
>   will balk if the parent folder is the current Eclipse workspace.
>   Perhaps, the recommendations presented here,
>   http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_Repositories are
>   being enforced in the tool? The final result is that the existing
>   project in the intended Eclipse workspace, is instead, “moved” to a
>   new or existing egit repository in HOME.

Comment: Try importing your project's local repository in eclipse.

Comment: I tried to import the projects using Git but it says that the projects are already in my workspace even if my local copies have been removed.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue. I created a bug report for it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=451521

So I don't think you were doing something wrong.

Comment: I got my files moved too with Eclipse 4.4.0 so this answer is the correct one for me

Comment: Same problem.  All files whipped out of designated Eclipse workspace.  Do these people ever bother testing anything before releasing new versions? Tiresome and unprofessional.

Answer (score 1):

Share project doesn't move files; [it just creates an empty Git repo](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Sharing). After creating the repo, you must add the files which you want to keep under version control. There must be something else which you did. Without additional information, there is no way for us to help you.

Comment: Hi, I did exactly the same with another folder in my local drive. My working directory is in the same folder as my repository. Does it explain why my files are removed?

Comment: Wrong.  At least at time of writing: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1) Build id: 20150109-0600

Comment: @mikerodent: It works with Kepler SR2 (4.3.2). Maybe a regression?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing you have to use (right-click on Project) Refactor --> Move (back to where it should be).  But this apparently takes these files out of version control!

Taken from: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1621217/#msg_1621217

NB this is a shocking bug and the Egit team need to sort it out ASAP.  Wouter submitted bug report in Nov 2014.